# Add user_data in ec2 instance using terraform with file variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, ec2-userdata

I am trying to create multiple ec2 instance using terraform modules. As every instance will have different user data, I want to do this but it's giving error

```
data "local_file" "user_data" {
  for_each = { for ec2 in var.ec2_instances : ec2.name => ec2 }
  filename = "${path.cwd}/${each.value.user_data}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "instances" {
  for_each = { for instance in var.ec2_instances : instance.name => instance }

  ami                    = each.value.ami
  instance_type          = each.value.type
  cpu_core_count         = each.value.cpu_core
  user_data_base64  = base64encode(data.local_file.user_data[each.value.name].rendered)
}
```

module.tf

```
module "ec2_app_demo" {
  source = "./aws-ec2-application/"

  ec2_instances     = var.ec2_instances
}
```

In the tfvars file

```
ec2_instances= [
{
name = test1
user_data = ec2_1.sh
},
{
name = test2
user_data = ec2_2.sh
}
]
```

Error:

> Error: Invalid function argument\n\n  on main.tf line 76, in data "local_file" "linux-vm-cloud-init":\n  76:   filename = file("${each.value.user_data}")\n

Please let me know if the file name can be used a variable.

The folder structure is below:
[image]

Comment: Are the shell scripts in the same directory as the terraform code?

Comment: Yes, same directory as terraform code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the shell files are in the same directory, it should be easy to achieve what you want. Additionally, the variable has to use quoted values:

```
ec2_instances= [
  {
    name = "test1"
    user_data = "ec2_1.sh"
  },
  {
    name = "test2"
    user_data = "ec2_2.sh"
  }
]
```

The `file` built-in function expect you to provide a path to the file [1], it has no knowledge if the file is in the same directory or not:

> `file` reads the contents of a file at the given path and returns them as a string.

As per the comments (h/t: @Marcin) in order for the code to work, the data source should be changed to this (the `file` is not required):

```
data "local_file" "user_data" {
  for_each = { for ec2 in var.ec2_instances : ec2.name => ec2 }
  filename = "${path.module}/../${each.value.user_data}"
}
```

**EDIT**: Based on the comments, the shell script is named differently compared to what was originally posted in the question for the variable value. For this to work, the variable value has to change to:

```
ec2_instances= [
  {
    name = "test1"
    user_data = "tmosquid02.sh"
  }
]
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/file

Comment: path.module goes to the child folder whereas the shell scripts are in parent folder where I am calling the modules

Comment: Ok, that's why I asked. Edited the answer.

Comment: This gives below error: Error: read /git/import_resources/XXXXX/EC2/: is a directory\n\n  on aws-ec2-application/main.tf line 74, in data \"local_file\" \"user_data\":\n  74: data \"local_file\" \"user_data\" {\n\n\n\n

Comment: @MarkoE There shoudn't be a `file` in `filename`. Otherwise entire content of a file is treated as a filename.

Comment: Ah, my bad, thanks, will fix that.

Comment: It's giving this error: Error: read ./: is a directory\n\n  on aws-ec2-application/main.tf line 74, in data \"local_file\" \"user_data\" I removed file   filename = "${path.root}/${each.value.user_data}"

Comment: Please show the directory structure then if you are facing the error.

Comment: added the screenshot

Comment: There are no shell scripts anywhere in that directory.

Comment: the tmosquid02.sh is the shell script

Comment: That is the user data shell script you want?

Comment: Yes correct. In case of multiple ec2 instance, we will add more shell script in same location

Comment: @MayaRay I added the change you need to have in your code.

Comment: Error: read ./: is a directory I am getting this error now. I tried with path.cwd  and path.module

Comment: Where are you trying to run the code from? The same directory level where `ec2.tf` is or where the `aws-ec2-appliction` code is?

Comment: I am running code where ec2.tf is

Comment: Can you try with `"${path.module}/../${each.value.user_data}"`?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `file`. Just the **path** is enough:

```
filename = "${path.module}/${each.value.user_data}"
```

Comment: I tried this, it's giving error:   Error: read ./: is a directory\n\n  on aws-ec2-application/main.tf line 74, in data \"local_file\" \"user_data\"

Comment: @MayaRay Then I would suggest starting with providing valid TF code. Your `ec2_instances` variable is not a valid TF code. This suggest that your real code is different that what you posted in the question, thus its not clear what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by doing below. I didn't need data source. Just added below:

```
user_data = each.value.user_data != "" ? file("${path.module}/../${each.value.user_data}") : null
```